# Winsock - Reconnecting client to server basics - TIME_WAIT

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2, winsockets

I have a TCP server/client set up and they communicate the way I generally want.

What I want to do now is add functionality that would allow the client to automatically reconnect to the server once a connection is lost. I'm having trouble finding complete information online on how to do this.

Details: 
-I only have 1 server and so far it only hosts at most 1 connection. 
-When either the client OR the server disconnects - both close (is it sensible to close both the server's and client's sockets like this?)

Ideally, I would like for the client to be able to reconnect to the same port on the server each time. I understand TIME_WAIT and why it is necessary. I don't really want to use SO_REUSEADDR unless I don't have another option. How is this generally handled? Should I open a new port on the Server side while it waits for the old socket to finish TIME_WAIT and basically alternate between the two ports (which means that the client would have to keep track of 2 possible ports)?

Thanks for your suggestions !

Comment: You should just accept that, once a TCP connection is gone, it's gone.  The client should not try to keep track of any ports, just loop around a connect() attempt, perhaps with a short sleep(), until one succeeds.  If there is some state that is server<>client specific, you should 'fixup' this on the new connection by having the client log in with some ID that identifies it so that the server can retrieve the state object for that client.  See @Dimitry answer that I voted up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TIME_WAIT is state of TCP connection, not the port. Every TCP connection identifies by tuple (local-address, local-port, remote-address, remote-port). So if the client connect to server using new (dynamic) local port then new TCP connection is created and TIME_WAIT isn't issue.

Comment: Does this mean that, for example, if the client were to:   
`1-client connect to the server on port A   
2-client disconnect   
3-client connect on port B   
4-client disconnect   
5-client connect on port A again`   
All steps within 10 seconds, that the server should **not** have to check the TIME_WAIT state ??? thanks

Comment: You miss client source port used to make connect to server. If client choose new source port on every connection, then nobody may care about TIME_WAIT. I don't understand your complex doubleport example.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how a server should handle a client disconnecting. Right now, upon disconnection, both the server AND client call shutdown(), closesocket() and wsacleanup(). Then, I manually input a new server port (which goes through create new socket, wsastartup, listen and bind) then connect the client to the new port #. Is this what basically should (has to) happen ? A new port (B != A) has to be assigned to the server socket each time the client disconnects ?

Comment: It's just from the client (user's) perspective, it is easier to have to only deal with 1 port # rather than 2 or more port #s when trying to connect to a server

Comment: NO! Server shouldn't change the port after each client disconnect. Server has listen socket that receive incoming connections, when server accept connection new (connection) socket is created. When you shutdown connection socket listen socket keep their live and can receive more (re)connections.

Comment: From client side you can create socket and connect to the server port from dynamic (system-allocated) port. When connection is broken you reconnect to the server from new port.

Comment: Ahh OK tyvm for the clarification I've made the adjustments.